# How to make an oplus in mhchem

Tags: symbols, mhchem, chemistry

I would like to have an oplus and an ominus in LaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}
\ce{A^\oplus + A^\ominus}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\ce{A$\!^\oplus$ + A$\!^\ominus$}` perhaps? The `mhchem` manual states that this is basically the way to escape to math

Comment: `\ce{A^{$\oplus$} + A^{$\ominus$}}`?

Comment: Thx that is the answer :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\oplus` and `\ominus` are math symbols and must be used in math mode. This is also true in `mhchem`'s formulas.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\ce{A+ + A-} \par
\ce{A^{$\oplus$} + A^{$\ominus$}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A sortcut is `\ce{A^$\oplus$ + A^$\ominus$}`

Comment: @mhchem that is no correct latex syntax (even if it works…).

Comment: It is 100% correct mhchem syntax. mhchem != LaTeX. `H2O+` and `^227_90Th+` aren't valid LaTeX syntax either.